# Identifying a badge/medal

Tags: world-war-two, military, world-war-one

Does anyone know what this is from and who had this? [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Queen's Own Cameron Highlanders.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_Own_Cameron_Highlanders)

[image]

> The Queen's Own Cameron Highlanders or 79th (The Queen's Own Cameron
>   Highlanders) Regiment of Foot was a line infantry regiment of the
>   British Army, raised in 1793. It amalgamated with the Seaforth
>   Highlanders (Ross-shire Buffs, The Duke of Albany's) to form the
>   Queen's Own Highlanders in 1961.